# submitting checkbox to php mail

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, contact-form

Update:

Thanks you for the help @fred, however my only problem is the response from the checkbox is all ways 'no'. What am I missing? I've been staring at this for hours now! My test file works fine no problem, only when i've split the code up as shown below.

HTML:

```
<form id="contactFormChina" action="phpfolder/priceschina-form.php" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Prices','Submit','Prices CHINA',1])" method="POST">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name *" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="email" value="" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email *" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Are you a Distributor / Reseller? *</label>
                    <div class="radio-group">
                      <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="distributor" id="distributor" value="Yes" required>
                        Yes </label>
                      <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="distributor" id="distributor2" value="No" required>
                        No </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Company / Facility *" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="department" id="department" placeholder="Department *" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Country *" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <textarea maxlength="2000" rows="3" class="form-control" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="How can we help you? *" required></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="Yes">
                  <label for="newsletter"><strong>I want to sign up for the newsletter.</strong></label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="alert email-success hidden" id="contactSuccessChina"> <strong>Thank You.</strong> We will contact you as soon as possible.</div>
                  <div class="alert alert-danger hidden" id="contactErrorChina"> <strong>Error!</strong> Sorry, there was an error with your details. </div>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit Request" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-loading-text="Loading...">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

PHP:

```
$to = 'my@email.com';

$subject = 'Price Info (China/Hong Kong) - ' . $_POST['name'];

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $name        = $_POST['name'];
    $email       = $_POST['email'];
    $distributor = $_POST['distributor'];
    $company     = $_POST['company'];
    $department  = $_POST['department'];
    $country     = $_POST['country'];
    $comments    = $_POST['comments'];
}

if (isset($_POST['newsletter']) && $_POST['newsletter'] == 'Yes') {
    $_POST['newsletter'] = 'Yes';
} else {
    $_POST['newsletter'] = 'No';
}

$fields = array(
    0 => array(
        'text' => '<b>Name',
        'val' => $_POST['name']
    ),
    1 => array(
        'text' => '<b>Email',
        'val' => $_POST['email']
    ),
    2 => array(
        'text' => '<b>Distributor / Reseller',
        'val' => $_POST['distributor']
    ),
    3 => array(
        'text' => '<b>Company / Facility',
        'val' => $_POST['company']
    ),
    4 => array(
        'text' => '<b>Department',
        'val' => $_POST['department']
    ),
    5 => array(
        'text' => '<b>Country',
        'val' => $_POST['country']
    ),
    6 => array(
        'text' => '<b>Comments',
        'val' => $_POST['comments']
    ),
    7 => array(
        'text' => '<b>Join the mailing list?',
        'val' => $_POST['newsletter']
    )
);

$message = "";

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $message .= $field['text'] . ":</b> " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
}

$headers = '';
$headers .= 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    $arrResult = array(
        'response' => 'success'
    );
} else {
    $arrResult = array(
        'response' => 'error'
    );
}
echo json_encode($arrResult);
?>
```

Comment: *Think `isset()`*.

Comment: Sidenote: You're using `checked` for it and that shouldn't be automatically checked when people sign up for something. What you're doing is illegal in many countries. The person needs to check the box themselves if they want to subscribe. If you were doing this in Canada, the Anti-Spam law http://fightspam.gc.ca/eic/site/030.nsf/eng/home would fine you in a New York minute.

Comment: ...oh, and that's a 1 million dollar minimum fine, I might add for personal use.

Comment: oh wow, thanks for that!
A major competitor has its checkbox selected, thats where I got the idea from.

Comment: You're welcome Ian. Well, at least you'll (now) have an edge over your competitor ;-) We don't take Spam lightly anymore in Canada, as patient and understanding as we are *lol* Cheers

Comment: I'm curious Ian; why did you unaccept my answer just now? there is no JS  in this question to support it

Comment: Sorry, thought maybe I could have selected more than one correct answer as each has been relevant to me solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What needs to be done here is to check if the checkbox is set and also assign `$_POST['newsletter']` to a "Yes" or to a "No". The POST array needs to exist rather than a variable assigned to a POST array, since you are using a `foreach` for all the POST arrays.

Sidenote: You'll need to adjust it and add the missing arrays.

What I tested this with is:

```
<form method="post">

    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="Yes">
    <label for="newsletter">
        <strong>
        I want to sign up for the newsletter.
        </strong>
    </label>

    <br>
    Email
    <input type="text" name="email">

    <br>
    Name
    <input type="text" name="name">

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

}

if(isset($_POST['newsletter']) && $_POST['newsletter'] == 'Yes')
{
    $_POST['newsletter'] = 'Yes';
}
else
{
    $_POST['newsletter'] = 'No'; 
}


$fields = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => '<b>Name',
            'val' => $_POST['name']
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => '<b>Email',
            'val' => $_POST['email']
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => '<b>Join the mailing list?',
            'val' => $_POST['newsletter'],
        )
);

foreach($fields as $field) {

        $message .=  $field['text'].":</b> " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
        // Testing with an echo
        // echo $message .=  $field['text'].":</b> " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    }
```

---

Plus as I stated in comments. You shouldn't make the checkbox already checked because that is illegal in many countries, including mine being Canada.

- There are laws against that.

My comment being:

You're using checked for it and that shouldn't be automatically checked when people sign up for something. What you're doing is illegal in many countries. The person needs to check the box themselves if they want to subscribe. If you were doing this in Canada, the Anti-Spam law http://fightspam.gc.ca/eic/site/030.nsf/eng/home would fine you in a New York minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['newsletter']) && 
   $_POST['newsletter'] == 'Yes') 
{
    echo "Need newsletter access.";
}
else
{
    echo "Do not Need newsletter access.";
}    

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Fixed!

Needed to add in a .js file

```
newsletter: $("input[name=newsletter]:checked").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get().join(",")
```

Comment: all nice and dandy, but you didn't post any JS in your original question. Why is that?